# Rails, for each checkbox in a form, create a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm confused about how to do this, basically what I have is a `Notification` model, and users `have_many` notifications. The issue is, I need to create a form so that it has checkboxes for each user, and if the user is checked, they get the notification.

Here is what I created so far, but I'm thinking the form itself shouldn't be for the notification model?

My controller:

```
class Admin::NotificationsController < AdminController
  respond_to :html

  def index
  end

  def new
    @notification = Notification.new
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @notification] do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :content %>

  <label>create for users:</label>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    [checkbox] <%= user.email %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I guess I just don't know where to start with the form, any help explaining how would really really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<%= f.association :users, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

Comment: It's weird, I get `Association :users not found`, even though all my associations are setup correctly!

Comment: Try `<%=  f.collection_check_boxes :user_ids, @users, :id, :email %>` also make sure that you have has_many and belongs_to associations correctly also see if you have notification_id field in User model.